# ECSlidingViewController pod installation error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to import `ECSlidingViewController` library to my iOS mobile application by using `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'ECSlidingViewController', '~> 2.0.3'
```

When Im trying to open workspace I get error:

[image: The document "" could not be opened]

When Im updating (`pod update`) I get error too: `[!] Oh no, an error occurred.`

NEW!!!

I have just found out that error causes symbol "&" in project name. Is it possible somehow to keep name with "&" symbol?

Comment: Which version of the XCode do you use?

Comment: Try to reinstall cocoapods again: sudo gem install cocoapods then check if there is any warning at the end of the installation.

Comment: I have just found out that error causes symbol "&" in project name. Is it possible somehow to keep name with "&" symbol?

Comment: There have been issues with symbol's like this in project names before. Please submit [an issue](https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues) about this so it can get fixed!

Comment: Keith Smiley, post your comment as a answer. You were right. This issue is fixed now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an cocoa pods issue with bad naming. I reported it and this issue will be fixed soon